# Update all WooCommerce product prices to 2 decimals in database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Many of my products have prices like `£3.4560` etc. I need them to rounded and stripped to just 2 in the database.

The output of 2 decimal places in WooCommerce is not enough and fails to work with a Tax Toggle plugin.

Is there a database query that can do this?

I've seen some bits on Rounding and Truncate but not sure how to execute this as my knowledge is poor.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so the below code works and changes the price in the database to 2 decimals. However, for the plugin to work, the product has to be updated by clicking the button. I guess this refreshes the content? So what I need is for every product to be"updated".

This is from the plugin author of Tax Toggle. "I'm not sure how you have entered the products into Woo but have a look at that process. I find that on any product once resaved (updated) then it works. So this indicates the prices have not been imported via the woocommerce save function and therefore is being imported incorrectly."

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:** *(Added some code to clear all related product transient cache)*

Here is some code that will update all the product prices (make a database backup before):

```
global $wpdb;
$postmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";
$posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";

// 1. First query: Get all prices
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT $postmeta.*
    FROM $postmeta
    INNER JOIN $posts ON $postmeta.post_id = $posts.ID
    WHERE $posts.post_type LIKE '%product%'
    AND $postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%price%'
    AND $postmeta.meta_value != ''
    ORDER BY $postmeta.meta_id ASC
" );

// iterating through each price and update it
foreach($results as $result){
    $meta_id    = $result->meta_id;
    $post_id    = $result->post_id;
    $meta_key   = $result->meta_key;
    $meta_value = number_format( $result->meta_value, 2 );

    // 2. Udating prices query
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "
        UPDATE $postmeta
        SET meta_id = $meta_id, post_id = $post_id, meta_key = '$meta_key', meta_value = '$meta_value'
        WHERE $postmeta.meta_id = %d
    ", $meta_id ) );

     // 3. Clear all related product transient cached data (refresh prices)
     wc_delete_product_transients($post_id);
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> Once saved, just browse any page of your site, check your database wp_postmeta table searching for **`‰price‰ LIKE meta_key`**. Now you can remove this code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I get this error when saving your code exactly as you say.

'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2000' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)'

Comment: This fails to complete the task I require. It changes none of the products prices to 2 decimal places, even after updating the file multiple times in Editor. The prices still have 4 decimal places. See here - http://imgur.com/a/6SutJ @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Thanks Loic! Prices have changed to 2 decimals in database now. However, to get it working on frontend, each product has to updated manually with the update button. Do you know of any way to update all products at once?

Comment: Is there some code that can enable the woocommerce save function action to apply for all products? This would save each product I'm guessing? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I have asked a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617720/how-to-apply-woocommerce-save-function-for-every-product

Comment: Thanks. When updating the code in Editor, the page loads for many minutes and gives HTTP ERROR 500. Prices still fail to update. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: @HarryNorman Alternatively, you could do first in menu WooCommerce Status > tools and delete the transcient for the products… After, if it doesn't work, as your prices are already updated in database, you can remove the bloc code for the ( final ) step 2  … Try it… then It will just remove/refresh the caches for all the prices . But I my case the code works (but I don't have a buch of prices)