# Woocommerce MySQL to update price of products in specific category

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to increase the price by a percentage of certain products that are in a specific category. I figured out the select statement that should work, but am having trouble combining it the update statement. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT * from `wp_term_relationships` where term_taxonomy_id=376 and object_id in(select ID from `wp_posts` where `post_type`='product' and     post_status='publish' and ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id)
```

This gives me the products that I need. Can I run an UPDATE (like below) on those products or do I need to combine them somehow?

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = meta_value * 1.40 where meta_key='_regular_price'
```

Comment: You will need to update also '_price' (the active price) and you will need to delete transient caches (if not you will see the old product prices even if they have been updated in database).

Comment: Understood. I figured as much but thanks! How can I run that update on the product ids I get back from the first SELECT query?

Comment: I have already done similar before. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664066/update-all-variations-prices-of-a-variable-product-in-woocommerce) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484681/update-all-woocommerce-product-prices-to-2-decimals-in-database) (may be others …) … In the first you get the Ids and then you update with those ids (see the links). But I am not an expert in SQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a MySQL query which'll serve your purpose.

**To update `_regular_price`**

```
UPDATE 
    `wp_postmeta` 
SET 
    `meta_value` = ROUND(`meta_value` * 1.40, 2) 
WHERE 
    meta_key = '_regular_price' 
    AND `post_id` IN (
        SELECT 
            `object_id` AS product_id 
        FROM 
            `wp_term_relationships` 
        WHERE 
            term_taxonomy_id = 376
            AND `object_id` IN (
                SELECT 
                    `ID` 
                FROM 
                    `wp_posts` 
                WHERE 
                    `post_type` = 'product' 
                    AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
                    AND `ID` = `object_id`
            )
    );
```

**To update `_price`**

```
UPDATE 
    `wp_postmeta` 
SET 
    `meta_value` = ROUND(`meta_value` * 1.40, 2) 
WHERE 
    meta_key = '_price' 
    AND `post_id` IN (
        SELECT 
            `object_id` AS product_id 
        FROM 
            `wp_term_relationships` 
        WHERE 
            term_taxonomy_id = 376
            AND `object_id` IN (
                SELECT 
                    `ID` 
                FROM 
                    `wp_posts` 
                WHERE 
                    `post_type` = 'product' 
                    AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
                    AND `ID` = `object_id`
            )
    );
```

Also you have to delete WooCommerce product price caching which is stored in `wp_options` table under **`_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_{{post_id}}`** **and `_transient_wc_var_prices_{{post_id}}`** in `option_name`

```
DELETE
FROM `wp_options`
WHERE (`option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc_var_prices_%'
    OR `option_name` LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_%')
```

*Above query is tested and worked for me.*

**Before running this query do take a database backup**

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Lance I am trying to do something similar except I want to update all prices by a percentage did you every modify your code to achieve this.

Comment: hi @rogue39nin, is this what you are trying to achieve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484681/update-all-woocommerce-product-prices-to-2-decimals-in-database

Comment: Thanks for the queries seem working changing prices but somehow the site still returns the old prices, I tried looking for _price in wp_postmeta and it returns the new price, please help if there is something im missing.

Comment: @ahmed: have you deleted the transient's ? I just tested now with latest version of WC and WP everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is another cool way to do it without touching MySQL.

Check out WordPress [Bulk Edit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Screen#Bulk_Edit)

Change the `Screen Options` to show all the products you have. If you have a LOT of products then you can do so by 500 by page.

Select All  -> `Bulk Options (edit)` -> `Select a Category` and **Apply**

It also allows you to increase the price of all by a fixed amount or a percentage. I hope this helps someone.

Not as flexible as MySQL but does a fantastic job in certain scenarios.